# Reversing a string given as input not returning reversed string

Tags: c#, string, reverse

I'm trying to create a basic string reverser, the object is to get the string as input from the user, and output it as a reversed string, I think I have it, except I'm not getting any output from my solution:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace StringReverser
{
    class ReverseString
    {
        static string Reverse(string input)
        {
            char[] toReverse = input.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(toReverse);
            return new string(toReverse);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter string to reverse: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Reverse(input);
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong to where I don't get output?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Reverse(input));`

Comment: Mike is saying you forgot to write the result back to the screen.

Comment: Well I feel pretty stupid now. To bad I can't downvote my own question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by Mike Christensen you should output your reversed string by calling `Console.WriteLine` or `Console.Write` if you do not like a linebreak after the output.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace StringReverser
{
    class ReverseString
    {
        static string Reverse(string input)
        {
            char[] toReverse = input.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(toReverse);
            return new string(toReverse);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter string to reverse: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Reverse(input));
        }
    }
}
```